# How to find the temperature difference over a specific plate given temperature difference between two plates?

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm having trouble solving this question where two metal plates are in thermal contact with each-other. I'm given the type of metals in each plate, the thickness and the overall temperature difference for both plate  however I don't understand how to find the temperature difference over a specific metal plate.

so far I've tried applying the heat conduction formula:

$
P_{cond}= \frac{kA\Delta T}{L}
$

and equating it for the other material

$
\frac{k_{Al}\Delta T}{L_{Al}} = \frac{k_{Pb}\Delta T}{L_{Pb}} 
$

I know that $\Delta T$ is the temperature difference of that specific plate, however I'm finding it hard to understand how to actually find this given the overall difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there! You've worked out that:

$$ \frac{k_{Al}\Delta T_{Al}}{L_{Al}} = \frac{k_{Pb}\Delta T_{Pb}}{L_{Pb}} $$

where $\Delta T_{Al}$ is the temperature drop in the aluminium plate and $\Delta T_{Pb}$ is the temperature drop in the lead plate. Now just use the fact that the sum of the two temperature drops is the total temperature drop:

$$ \Delta T_{Al} + \Delta T_{Pb} = \Delta T $$

Now you have two simultaneous equations for the two variables $\Delta T_{Al}$ and $\Delta T_{Pb}$. Just solve the equations.

Comment: So if I were to separate the temps as $T_1, T_2 and T_3$, $\Delta T_{overall}$ would equal $T_1-T_3$ right?

Comment: Wait! like this? $\frac{k_{Al}L_{Pb}}{L_{Al}k_{Pb}} \Delta T_{Al} =\Delta T_{Pb}
$
Then sub into the sum of $\Delta T_{overall}$